# How to get audio stream from Twilio Video and send it to AWS Transcribe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-video, amazon-transcribe

I'm trying to create a Voice to text app using the Twilio Video service with AWS Transcribe. I saw examples with Twilio Calls + Twilio Media Stream + Google\AWS Transcribe, but I'm not sure that media stream will work with Twilio Video. Is there any way how to implement it?